# Why is this reading as undefined for ReactDOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to just set up a basic react script like this

```
const subTable = document.getElementById("sub-table");
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

 console.log (subTable);
  const App = () => {
    return <div>Hello World!</div>;
  };

  ReactDOM.render(<App />, subTable);
```

I was originally just using @wordpress/scripts which contained both react and react-dom, but I then also tried installing them directly so now my package shows:

```
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^25.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```

But, I didn't want to have two copies, so I uninstalled react react-dom and now just have this as my current json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.7",
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^25.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.8.0",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.2.0",
    "flowbite": "^1.5.4",
    "tw-elements": "^1.0.0-alpha13"
  }
```

Reading the ID, this is what the console.log shows

```
<div id="sub-table"></div>
```

So I'm at a loss.  Any suggestions why I'm getting this error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'render')

Update:

Uninstalled flowbite and tw-elements to make sure their JS isn't interfering. Current json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.7",
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^25.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.8.0",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.2.0"
  }
```

Still getting the undefined render

Update 2:

I noticed that react and react-dom were loading before my JS so I set the priority in the enqueue and now my JS loads after.

This appears to have fixed the problem!

Comment: So you're loading two versions of each library?

Comment: Note that [React 18 has a different render API](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html) to 17. You should upgrade your code.

Comment: @isherwood I tried with just @wordpress/scripts which include react and reactDOM, then I tried installing them individually. Both had same result

Comment: Your code is misleading. You specifically indicated that this is what's currently there. Please revise to only show what you're actually using.

Comment: @iserwood Updated with the exact current file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like react-dom does not have a default import, but only named ones. Try it with this:

```js
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Comment: Still getting an undefined with that

Answer (score 0):

The react and react-dom files were loading before my JS file. I just had to change the order of load